# Google Search Appliance error - ProcessNode: Does not contain a valid host, skipping record with url

Tags: post, google-search-appliance

I am using Google Search Appliance in my application for search functionality. The data to be searched are pushed into the GSA by POSTing the data as XML into the GSA.

After POSTing the data from a windows service, i am getting a success message. But when i check the feed section in the GSA console i am seeing this error against the XML that is pushed. Any idea what this is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the host of the affected element contain a protocol in front of the url and ends with a slash if its the root url of a domain? Or is the host without a toplevel domain?

```
http://server.tld -> valid
http://server     -> invalid
```

The server url without domain is sadly not possible in the GSA, even if thats standard in intranet sites. In this case you have to use the server url including the network domain.

It is at least not a xml structure error but one with an invalid url submitted. You can try to add the affected url into the Start Patterns of the GSA to test if the same error is occurring.